# Typecasting word to half-word MIPS

Tags: casting, mips

As part of a programming exercise I am required to return an integer from a function and then typecast it into a short. Thus far I have:

```
.text
j main

getRandom: # Produce a random integer between max and min
    sub  $t0, $a1, $a0 # max - min
    addi $t0, $t0, 1   # max - min + 1

    addi $sp, $sp, -16 # Allocate 16 bytes of stack memory
    sw   $a0, 0($sp)
    sw   $a1, 4($sp)
    sw   $t0, 8($sp)

    li   $v0, 41       # get a random int
    syscall            # $a0 = rand()

    lw   $t0, 0($sp)   # $t0 = min
    lw   $t1, 4($sp)   # $t1 = max
    lw   $t2, 8($sp)   # $t2 = max - min + 1
    addi $sp, $sp, 16  # Reset stack pointer

    remu $a0, $a0, $t2 # rand() % (max - min + 1)
    add  $v0, $a0, $t0 # min + rand() % (max - min + 1)
    jr   $ra

main:
    li   $a0, 10     # Low bound
    li   $a1, 100    # Upper bound
    jal getRandom
    move $a0, $v0

    # Perform typecast
    la   $t0, 0($a0) # Get $a0's address
    lh   $a0, 0($t0) # Load 2 bytes from $a0's address

    li   $v0, 1
    syscall
```

The compiler is throwing an error at the "lh $a0, 0($t0)" line, but I'm not sure how else one could typecast it. I would appreciate an alternative way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: _"throwing an error"_ **What** error? In any case, you can always simulate `lh` with `lb` or `lw` and some bitwise logic.

Comment: Mars unfortunately doesn't say. But how would you accomplish this with bitwise logic?

Comment: _"Mars unfortunately doesn't say"_. Sure it does. It says "Runtime exception at 0x00400064: address out of range 0x0000001e". That's information you should've included in your question.

Comment: Also, `Get $a0's address` makes no sense. Registers don't have addresses. If all you wanted was to clear the top 16 bits of a register, just use `AND`, or two shifts.